# Exportar dados do Google Sheets para o R

Tags: r, google-sheets

Galera, tudo bem? Sou iniciante em R e tenho uma dúvida: É possível, e se possível, qual o caminho pra exportar dados de uma tabela do google sheets (Ou Drive) para o R. Existe alguma biblioteca pra isso?

Comment: Podes tentar usar o pacote `googlesheets`. [Aqui](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/googlesheets.pdf) o manual e [aqui](http://www.opiniomics.org/reading-data-from-google-sheets-into-r/) um exemplo.

Comment: Ajudou muito! Consegui fazer a exportação! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @WillianVieira, que tal postar como resposta para ajudar quem procure esta pergunta no futuro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o pacote [`googlesheets`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/googlesheets.pdf), [aqui](http://www.opiniomics.org/reading-data-from-google-sheets-into-r/) vai um link demonstrando um exemplo de utilização desse pacote.

Para encontrar outros pacotes com palavras-chave que ainda não conhecemos, além de procurar no google, existe algumas opções direta o ambiente R:

#### função `findFn()` do pacote `sos`:

```
sos::findFn('google')
sos::findFm('sheets')
```

Essa função retorna uma página web com uma tabela de possíveis funções e seus respectivos pacotes.

#### função `search.cran()` do pacote `NCmisc`:

```
NCmisc::search.cran('google')
# $google
#  [1] "googleAnalyticsR"        "googleAuthR"
#  [3] "googleCloudStorageR"     "googleComputeEngineR"
#  [5] "googledrive"             "googleformr"
#  [7] "GoogleKnowledgeGraphR"   "googleLanguageR"
#  [9] "googlenlp"               "googlePolylines"
# [11] "googlePrintr"            "googlePublicData"
# [13] "googlesheets"            "googleVis"
# [15] "googleway"               "plotGoogleMaps"
# [17] "RGoogleAnalyticsPremium" "RGoogleFit"
# [19] "RgoogleMaps"             "rgoogleslides"


NCmisc::search.cran('sheets')
# $sheets
# [1] "googlesheets"
```

Se a palavra-chave é comum, podemos utilizar a função `grep()` para encontrar uma segunda palavra-chave na lista:

```
google <- NCmisc::search.cran('google')[[1]]

google[grep('sheet', google)]
# [1] "googlesheets"
```

Ou simplesmente usar mais de uma palavra-chave na função `search.cran()`:

```
NCmisc::search.cran(c('google','sheet'))
# [1] "episheet" "googlesheets" "gsheet"
```

Mais opões para a procura de pacotes estão disponíveis [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395180/best-way-to-search-for-r-packages).